# ¿como hacer una relacion de una tabla en una columna? Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

quiero saber si se puede hacer una tabla guarde datos que configura la visualizacion de una tabla.
estos son las columnas que lleva, falta la que identifica que tabla tiene esa configuracion 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta tabla es un ejemplo, quiero que cuando consulte esta tabla tambien me traiga la configuracion que tiene guardada en la otra tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A qué le llamas configuración, no sería registro? ¿Quieres crear una restricción foránea? ¿Porqué usas el tag VS2015?

Comment: si un registro , si algo si pero de la tabla , el tag es por si hay algo que tomar en cuenta cuando quiera hacer la consulta en vs15 formsWind

Comment: Si quieres una relación entre tablas, deberías indicar de que tipo sería: Uno a Uno (1-1), Uno a varios (1-*). Por ejemplo, una mascota tendrá solo una configuración, sería de uno a uno. Una mascota tendrás varias configuraciones, sería de uno a varios. O de varios a varios...

Comment: seria uno a uno